# Linux bash 4.4 issue

Tags: bash

While executing bash script getting the below error in bash 4.4 but same working in bash 4.2

```
unset: [$reqStatusArrayLength-2]: bad array subscript
```

Comment: Bash 4.4 is included in Ubuntu 18.04, which is now end of life, and therefore off-topic here.

Comment: @ArturMeinild you can install any version of bash on any version of Ubuntu though, and the OP also mentioned 4.2, so this could just be a development environment, being used to test different bash versions.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include the relevant part of the script so we can reproduce the error. If you are indeed using Ubuntu 18.04, then please delete and ask on [unix.se] instead. However, wherever you ask, we will need to see the script. We can't debug code we cannot see.

Comment: Of course - more details are needed indeed.

Comment: we would need the whole script. And possibly a list of difference between 4.2 and 4.4 Does it work in 5.2?

Answer (score 0):

Guessing as you have not shown relevant portions of your script:

Add:
`echo $reqStatusArrayLength-2`
just before the line where your script stops.

It is likely to print either:

- a number LESS THAN ZERO, or
- a number larger than the number of elements in your array

*(subscript <=> index into the array).*